# How do I paste an Excel sheet to the questions?

Tags: support, tables

How do I paste an Excel sheet to the questions?

I am trying to make it a nice format, so it can be easily answered, but I'm having trouble with it.

Comment: [Sort of related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables)

Comment: Additionally, I *highly* doubt you need to show your entire worksheet to get help.  Why not state what trouble you're having, and what you've tried to do to fix it? If anything, we'd just need a small range to look at and help, not the entire sheet.  I'd look over [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more help.

Comment: Thanks Batman.  I'll try to elaborate it in a question.  Hopefully it won't get completely down voted, which happens easily on here

Comment: @Tommac725 There's no real support for Excel Sheet rendering in markdown. You can provide a screenshot, if it's really important and relevant for your question.

Comment: > posts meta question on StackOverflow > snarks about being downvoted > mfw greentext in SO comment

Comment: _"Trying to make it a nice format so it can be easily answered but I'm having trouble with it. "_ Could you elaborate what your specific troubles are please? As mentioned there's no direct way.

Comment: Without specifics, the only additional advice I can think of is to look at existing Excel questions to see how other users handle it. Try to find something close to your question (though you may have done that already to find dupes) or search for a question you'd imagine would require showing the sheet. You could also look at database questions to see how they handle questions about tables without being able to insert tables.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't.  If your question requires someone download and examination of your Excel document, that question isn't appropriate on Stack Overflow. You need to work more on your issue in order to isolate it to the point where you can fit it, in its entirety, within the question space.

If you just want to share some relevant sample data, you won't get any support in the Markdown editor for formatting your data nicely. It's unfortunate, but true. You might find some relevant questions on meta.stackexchange.com asking for this feature. Go search for them and show them some support.

In the meantime, you can use external tools to format your data nicely.  The one I use is *[Format Text as Table](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/)* (no affiliation, bro). You can also export your relevant data from excel in a format which aids comprehension and paste the result, but depending on your data that may not be enough.

I would strongly advise not taking images of your data if you mean to share it with those you are asking for help. Images of text make it harder to help, usually.

Answer (score 1):

There's no *table formatting*, and if you try to make one in code blocks [it will look broken on a phone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73567/197901).

The most portable and accessible way is to simulate the table with [some clever MathJax](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3911/23788), but it doesn't look like it's enabled on Stack Overflow.

Best solution remains to use your favorite snipping tool to copy the relevant part of the screen into the clipboard, and then Ctrl+G and paste, to get the picture into your post.

Comment: _"... it doesn't look like it's enabled on Stack Overflow."_ It's definitely not available.

Comment: Best solution remains reducing it so you don't need an actual excel-sheet, and for sure not a picture of one, but can give all pertinent info with prose and maybe a code-block or two.

Comment: There is [table support now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support). Perhaps it is time for an update?